# Getting KeyError 'password' for user creation and authentication in Django Rest framework

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, token, user-registration

While testing my user_app API in postman, I'm getting

KeyError at /account/register/
'password'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8010/account/register/
Django Version: 4.1
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:
'password'
Exception Location: C:...\watchmate\user_app\api\serializers.py, line 28, in save
Raised during:  user_app.api.views.registration_view

Test:

username        example
email           example@xyz.com
password        example123
password2       example12

This is my user_app.api.views.py:

`from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from user_app.api.serializers import RegistrationSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['POST',])
def registration_view(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is my watchmate\user_app\api\serializers.py:

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

```
password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'password'}, write_only=True)

class Meta: 
    model = User
    field = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'password2']
    extra_kwargs = {'password': { 'write_only':True}}

def save(self):

    password = self.validated_data['password']
    password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

    if password != password2:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'error':'Password is not matching!'})`
```

I'm expecting the raised error written in serializers.py in postman output:

{'error':'password2 is not same as password!'}

Please see what's wrong with the codes that is causing this error.

Comment: everything is correct, can you please add missing code in serializers

Comment: yes sure, please add the missing code

Comment: @TanveerAhmad, are you saying it's possible to test the Validation error message in postman before that? But I'm getting KeyError, the moment I try to test it. Can you tell me how to test the validation error correctly?

Comment: yes you can test to debug your code